# Accessing sub context of a rule context in Antlr4 using visitor

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I am trying to parse Java class files using Java.g4 grammar and Antlr4.
There is a particular parser rule as follows:

```
classOrInterfaceType
:   Identifier typeArguments? ('.' Identifier typeArguments? )*
;
```

I am parsing it in my visitor class in this way:

```
public String visitClassOrInterfaceType(JavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceTypeContext ctx) {
    StringBuilder clsIntr = new StringBuilder("");
    int n = ctx.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        TerminalNode id = ctx.Identifier(i);
        if(id!=null){
            clsIntr.append(id.getText()).append(" ");
        }
        TypeArgumentsContext typArgCtx =ctx.typeArguments(i);
        if(typArgCtx!=null){
            String val = this.visitTypeArguments(typArgCtx);
            clsIntr.append(val);
        }
    }
    return clsIntr.toString();
}
```

Is this correct or there is some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks ok, even though that ultimately depends on what you are actually trying to do. My crystal ball tells me you try to reconstruct the original query text by walking the parse tree. However, you can get that much simpler. Each parse context has start and stop members that hold tokens for the parsed text range this context stands for. You could use those to directly get the original text exactly like it was entered (via the token stream and the token's positions).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I am trying to create the original query text. Spot On!!. But if I create them using token stream, I wont be able to create my query domain class objects. These objects will be required for further processing of query.